# Is it possible to create an array of Controllers in JavaFX?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, fxml

I've had a good search and either I'm not using the right terminology or this question hasn't appeared yet. I've been coding in Java for a few years and I've just started playing with Java FX over the last few weeks.

### Context:

I'm trying to create an app that is effectively a quiz, but instead of having a new Pane/Tab for each question, I'd like to have them appear side by side.

I have created a questionController for a single question, but I'm unsure of the best way of creating many questionControllers that are all uniquely identifiable by the fx:id's.

I'd like my GUI to be scaleable so the user can select the number of questions displayed per round. I can't seem to work out how to do this without manually setting creating views with different numbers of questionControllers.

### Things I've tried

- Adding controller gridPane,
- Importing the controller in the FXML

But this aren't scaleable as my buttons just become button0 - buttonN

If you require any more information, please let me know.

#### Question Controller.java

```
public class QuestionController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private ComboBox<String> chordCombo;

    @FXML
    private Label questionField;

    @FXML
    private Button submitButton;

    @FXML
    private ToggleGroup answerGroup;

    @FXML
    private RadioButton toggle0, toggle1, toggle2, toggle3, toggle4;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL fxmlFileLocation, ResourceBundle resources) {

        submitButton.setOnAction((event) -> {
            System.out.println("Submit Logic");
        });

        answerGroup.selectedToggleProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Toggle>() {
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Toggle> ov, Toggle old_toggle, Toggle new_toggle) {
                if (answerGroup.getSelectedToggle() != null) {
                    System.out.println(answerGroup.getSelectedToggle().toString());
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

#### QuestionController.fxml

```
<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="235.0" prefWidth="203.0" styleClass="layout" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="uk.co.temp.QuestionController">
   <children>
      <BorderPane layoutX="-11.0" layoutY="35.0" prefHeight="235.0" prefWidth="203.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
         <bottom>
            <Button fx:id="submitButton" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Submit" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
               <padding>
                  <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
               </padding>
               <BorderPane.margin>
                  <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
               </BorderPane.margin>
            </Button>
         </bottom>
         <top>
            <Label fx:id="questionField" text="Insert Question Here" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
               <padding>
                  <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
               </padding>
               <BorderPane.margin>
                  <Insets left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
               </BorderPane.margin>
            </Label>
         </top>
         <center>
            <GridPane BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
              <columnConstraints>
                <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
              </columnConstraints>
              <rowConstraints>
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                  <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                  <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
              </rowConstraints>
               <children>
                  <RadioButton fx:id="toggle0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Answer A">
                     <toggleGroup>
                        <ToggleGroup fx:id="answerGroup" />
                     </toggleGroup></RadioButton>
                  <RadioButton fx:id="toggle1" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Answer B" toggleGroup="$answerGroup" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                  <RadioButton fx:id="toggle2" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Answer C" toggleGroup="$answerGroup" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                  <RadioButton fx:id="toggle3" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Answer D" toggleGroup="$answerGroup" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
                  <RadioButton fx:id="toggle4" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Answer E" toggleGroup="$answerGroup" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
               </children>
               <padding>
                  <Insets top="10.0" />
               </padding>
            </GridPane>
         </center>
      </BorderPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Hey mate, how about assigning some variables to the buttons that then are being interpreted in the controller? So, instead of creating 40 controllers for 4 questions, your controller just reads Button.getQuestion() (ranges from 0-9) and Button.getAnswer (ranges from 0-4).

Comment: How are you loading `QuestionController.fxml`? If you want to load an arbitrary number of copies of it, then surely that's better done in Java (as opposed to FXML using `<fx:include>`). Then it's trivial to put all the controllers in a list or array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
TilePane pane = new TilePane(); // or whatever you are putting the questions in...

int numQuestions = ... ;

QuestionController[] controllers = new QuestionController[numQuestions];

for (int questionNumber = 0 ; questionNumber < numQuestions ; questionNumber++) {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("path/to/QuestionController.fxml"));
    pane.getChildren().add(loader.load());
    controllers[questionNumber] = loader.getController();
}
```

Obviously if the `TilePane` (or whatever) is defined in another FXML file and injected into another controller, you can put the same code in an event handler or initialize method, as needed, in that controller.

Comment: That's perfect. Thank you. I knew it wouldn't be too difficult.